# treeAggregate use case explanation

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to understand treeAggregate but there isn't enough examples online.

So does the following code merges the elements of partition then calls makeSummary and in parallel do the same for each partition (sums the result and summarizes it again) then with depth set to (lets say) 5, is this repeated 5 times?

The result I want to get from these is to summarize the arrays until I get one of them.

```
val summary = input.transform(rdd=>{
   rdd.treeAggregate(initialSet)(addToSet,mergePartitionSets,5)
    // this returns Array[Double] not rdd but still
})

val initialSet = Array.empty[Double]
def addToSet = (s: Array[Double], v: (Int,Array[Double])) => {
val p=s ++ v._2
val ret = makeSummary(p,10000)
ret
}
val mergePartitionSets = (p1: Array[Double], p2: Array[Double]) => {
val p = p1 ++ p2
val ret = makeSummary(p,10000)
ret
}

//makeSummary selects half of the points of p randomly
```

Comment: https://umbertogriffo.gitbooks.io/apache-spark-best-practices-and-tuning/content/treereduce_and_treeaggregate_demystified.html